# How can I check if 2 hours has passed?

Tags: javascript

I want to check if 2hours passed then do some steps. This is what I've tried so far

```
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getHours() + d.getMinutes();

if(time >= 120) {
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setTimeout` function to do stuffs in 2 hours. To cancel the timeout task, simply use `clearTimeout` to stop it.

```js
var timeoutId = setTimeout( function(){
  alert( '2 hours passed' );
}, 2*60*60*1000 );

// clearTimeout( timeoutId );
```

Comment: Am I supposed to wait for 2 hours to see the alert :P

Comment: If you are willing to :P

Answer (score 2):

I like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/)

```
let twoHoursLater = moment().add({hours: 2})
```

after some time passes, this check will return true when 2 hours passes

```
moment().isAfter(twoHoursLater)
-> true
```

Oh, and a plugin "timer" based on moment, [here](https://github.com/SeverinDK/moment-timer)

```
npm install moment-timer
```

then in javascript, use the `duration` and `timer`, like so

```
let timer = new moment.duration(2, 'hours').timer(callback);
timer.start();
function callback() {
  /* magic happens */
}
```

Another simple way is to just use javascript's native timeout, in this example, a callback is invoked after 2 hours.

```
setTimeout(callback, 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not clear. **@Thum Choon Tat** answer is fine if you just want to do stuff without page refresh.Every page refresh will calculate the time from 0 second.If You want to check weather 2 hours passed or not ignoring page refresh, you have to set a reference time from which you will calculate how much time have been passed. You can use https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

This is Jquery Cookie to set reference time. then get current time as you are doing. now compare this current time with your reference time.